# Excel VB macro stopped working after Google switched from Google Insights to Google Trends

Tags: api, vba, excel

I had an Excel VB macro that automatically download CSV files from Google Insights, it was working fine and the piece of code that downloads the CSV file is:

```
OutputFile = "http://google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=" _
            & termsAndTickers(counter, 1) & "&cmpt=q&content=1&export=2"
```

However, after Google switched from Google Insights to Google Trends, the code above stopped working. I've changed the "insights" to "trends" but that didn't help.

I've also been searching within Google Trends source code and couldn't locate an export link. Is there an API available? Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Would you be so kind to add your vba script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OutputFile = "http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&q=" & searchTerms & "&content=1&export=1"
```

where searchTerms is a space encoded string, e.g.: pacquiao%20marquez